# Heroku and Devise error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have just updated my Devise to 1.2 and it gives med the following error on Heroku:

```
"Devise changed how it stores objects in session. If you are seeing this message, you can fix it by changing one character in your cookie secret or cleaning up your database sessions if you are using a db store."
```

How can i clean up my database sessions in my heroku DB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
heroku rake db:sessions:clear
```

Will empty your sessions table

Comment: Just tried that, I get PGError: ERROR:  relation "sessions" does not exist
: DELETE FROM sessions

Comment: The problem is that the command above reset session-data stored in the sessions table, but it doesn't solves resetting session variables...